# run MongoDB MapReduce periodically

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, schedule

Anybody knows how can I run mapreduce in mongodb every one hour or one day?
I know I can do it in my application or with the OS, but I'm looking for something inside the mongodb shell.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm commenting because this isn't an answer to your question, but scheduling of mapreduce is usually done with other packages like Oozie or Azkaban.  Not that I recommend those over others I didn't mention, but those are the two I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to look at running a cronjob, or something similar, and passing a javascript file into the Mongo shell.